# Bundle Adjustment for Image Stitching

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-stitching

I am making simple image stitching script using matlab. I have now code that takes in ordered sequence of images(I0 I1 I2 I3...). For each image I extract SIFT descriptors and match them between each image pair. (find matches between I0-I1 then I1-I2...). I use ransac to figure out inliers and to fit a Homography between each pair. (H01=>I0-I1). Then I stitch the images together, I0 with I1 then (I0I1) to I2 and so on. (Basic panorama making I guess).

But, now I want to try to implement bundle adjustment to correct for the projection error in the whole image. I have read something about bundle adjustment in Szeliski computer vision book (but I find it more about BA in 3D reconstruction and I am not sure how to use it in 2D images stitching). Then I have also looked at [this paper](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/jchai/CPSC641/iccv2003.pdf).

I am not sure where to start, the paper is using more complex stitching and all discussion about camera models a bit confusing as I cannot connect these discussion to my simple application. Can someone help me to get started with this? Or point me towards some more suitable material where bundle adjustment is applied in simple panorama making? pseudo code of what I need do can also be helpful.

Comment: Constructing panorams form arbirary (even sorted) images is not at all simple. If you don't understand the camera model in Brown's paper, you should probably make use of an existing tool. Also, for joint homography estimation you don't need bundle adjustment, just use a nonlinear optimization like Levenberg–Marquardt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I have found set of consistent inliers with RANSAC I use them to fit a homography between each image pair (I1-I2, I2-I3) and I do that by solving the non-linear least squares problem via the Levenberg-Marquardt. Is that what you mean with using nonlinear optimization instead of bundle adjustment or would I need to look at all homographies in the optimization problem?

Comment: Acctually, forget what I said about joint homography estimation. You of course need global parameters to jointly optimize. Either way, bundle adjusment solves a problem (3D reconstruction and camera estimation) that needs parallaxes (translations), something you want to avoid in parnoramas. So I'd suggest you solve for a shared camera  (focal length) and rotations.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I was wondering if you would not mind sharing what method you ended up using? I am in a similar position as I have implemented pairwise correspondence matching and computing the homographies but am having issues figuring out how to do the bundle adjustment refinement step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have tried the first two steps and now the third step is the refinement through a bundler. I would strongly recommend you to read Hartley Zisserman book , Multiple view geometry, Appendix 6. Clear pseudo code is provided for LM based least square estimation for error refinement.

Now for your problem, you are trying to refine the homography to get a better match. So your error is a photometric error, similar to x1'Hx2. This case is also provided in the appendix.